# Change URL for all php files in a folder using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Does anyone know how to change the URL for all php files inside a subfolder of the root directory and also remove `.php`?

`http://localhost/pages/x.php`
to
`http://localhost/x`

Example:
`http://localhost/pages/example.php`
to
`http://localhost/example`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, which only executes if the request exists in `pages` and doesn't exist in root. So existing items in root don't get rewritten.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ pages/$1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^x$ page/x.php [L]
RewriteRule ^example$ pages/example.php [L]
```